# Why a batch processing of ffmpeg is freezing the system?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, parallel-processing, batch-processing, executorservice

I have a requirement of splitting smaller chunks of videos from 50+ mp4 source files for 5000+ records.  Each record may result in 2 or 3 smaller chunks from as many source files out of those 50+.

The logic to determine which source file to be picked up is written in Java and then fed to `ffmpeg` on `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` using `ExecutorService` with `newFixedThreadPool` as below:

```
private static boolean processqueue(ArrayList<String> cmds) {
    final ExecutorService pool;
    int threadsnum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()-2;
    pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsnum);

    for(final String cmd: cmds){ 
        pool.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(cmd);
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    pool.shutdown();
                }
            }
        });
    }                   
    pool.shutdown();

    // wait for them to finish for up to one minute.
    try {
        if(!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
            pool.shutdownNow();
        }

        //Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
        if(!pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
            System.err.println("Pool did not shutdown properly");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        pool.shutdownNow();
        //Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return false;
    }                   

    return true;
}
```

the String `cmd` value is one of these based on *split* or *merge* requirement:

for split:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:08 -i E:/tmp/fin12.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy E:/tmp/Intermed/0136f.mp4
```

or

for merge:

```
ffmpeg -y -i E:/tmp/Inter/0136c0.mp4 -i E:/tmp/Inter/0136c1.mp4 -i E:/tmp/Inter/0136f.mp4 -i E:/tmp/Jingle.mp4 -i E:/tmp/wm1280.png -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv][4:v]overlay=x=0:y=H-overlay_h[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" E:/tmp/final/0136.mp4
```

On first attempt, only 250 records were processed. And, on subsequent attempt of balance records processing, it threw below exception; but, processed another 300 records:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ffmpeg": CreateProcess error=1455, The paging file is too small for this operation to complete
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
```

And, this code freezes often. Why is `ExecutorService` not holding up the queue to process all the records and exit gracefully? What am I doing wrong?

**Note** : I'm calling Java class from windows batch script by passing relevant arguments which is executed from command line.

Comment: Your java code is getting in the way of normal debugging: "The paging file is too small for this operation to complete" is a windows error that you get when you need more memory than windows can give you, either because of other applications/processes hogging memory, or because there flat out isn't any memory left to allocate. So: have you tried looking at memory usage in task manager while you're running this monster operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting an execution, but not waiting for it to finish, so your threadpool just starts as many processes as there are commands. I'm not sure what the rest of your try/catch is trying to do. I'd suggest you use a CountdownLatch. Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> cmds = Lists.newArrayList("sleep 1", "sleep 2", "sleep 3");

    final ExecutorService pool;
    int threadsnum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 2;
    pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsnum);


    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(cmds.size());


    for (final String cmd : cmds) {
        pool.submit(() -> {
            try {
                System.out.println("to be executed: " + cmd);
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();
                latch.countDown();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }

    try {
        latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (latch.getCount() > 0) {
            System.out.println("Waited long enough. There are " + latch.getCount() + " threads still running");
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
    System.out.println("Completed.");

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.  You saved my day!  `waitFor()` did the trick.  I had to switch back to pre-1.8 submit syntax as my environment doesn't support Lambda expressions.  And, CountDownLatch is icing on the cake..

Comment: I guess I was too quick in acknowledging the solution.  It worked perfectly for *split*; but, nothing happens for *merge* or `ffmpeg concat` commands even after increasing `latch.await` time.  Typically, the *merge* takes 10-20s  on my system depending on number of input files and their size. So, I tried 30 seconds to 2 minutes `latch` time.  But, the process never stops (had to forcefully abort), log shows #of threads running and "completed" statements.  Any ideas?

Comment: The command you run has no impact on the code above. Latch time is the time it waits for ALL jobs to complete. So if you have 30 jobs, each taking 20s to run, and a pool of say 4, it'll take a little over 2 minutes to run (30*20)/4. You'll have IDLE threads in the pool until it is shutdown. My guess is that there's something in the command you're sending that is not working right. Try capturing the output stream from the process and/or the exit code and output those to console to see what's going on.

Comment: D, apparently, there's some impact of command line arguments as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` doesn't behave the same as Shell.  [issues-in-executing-ffmpeg-command-in-java-code-in-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45554501/issues-in-executing-ffmpeg-command-in-java-code-in-linux) and [when-runtime-exec---won-t.html](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).  I had to correct the code accordingly and everything is working fine now.  Thanks again.